# Multiple nav-pills with data-toggle bootstrap issue

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

My page is having cloned multiple nav with same class and id names. While navigating with `nav-pills` and `data-toggle` only 1st set is reflecting with selected other sets are not reflecting with selected.

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a> </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#office" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Office</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">Home</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="office">Office</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a> </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#office" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Office</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">Home</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="office">Office</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jithendra/8yfLtdas/)

Comment: In HTML, [IDs must be unique to the DOM tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page). You might try using different IDs for the second set of nav/panes, something like `#home2` and `#office2`. [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/asLnuphd/).

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique in the whole page